# In c++, difference between linking a class object and just including it.

Tags: c++, linking

this is my first time here.

I'm a physics grad student and I've recently found a research group to work with. We study statistical mechanics using computer models, so there is a significant programming aspect to it.

My first job has been to take the old data analysis code (written in java) and clean it up in c++. The guy before me who wrote the original program used the traditional physics method of using an enormous amount of spaghetti code and shoving it all in a constructor. This irked me quite a bit, so I divided it up into separate classes and now it has a reasonable class structure.

In the past, whenever we had defined a class we would put its definitions and its methods in a header function, then to use it we would just include it. I know this breaks the rules of how to use .h and .cpp files, but is there any reason other than code etiquette to compile and link a class object rather than include it?

Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 5):

The idea of headers is that we separate the public interface (i.e. declarations) from internal implementation details (i.e. the actual method bodies). This split has all kinds of advantages:

- There's a helper function I need? Let's just put it into the `.cpp` file, and outside code cannot see it. I can also do things like `using std` without interfering with other code.
- We are stuck in a C mindset and want to use a macro? Declare it in the `.cpp` file to avoid polluting outside code.
- There is a bug in a method? After fixing it, we only need to recompile that single `.cpp` file and re-link the application. This is much faster than recompiling *everything*.
- Related to that: header files are often included multiple times, and are therefore recompiled again and again … conserver compilation time, and put as little information as possible into the headers.
- Headers make the handling of cyclic dependencies across multiple files possible.

There are also a few drawbacks with headers, but you can't do anything to change that: headers are code duplication, they are idiotic language design, the C preprocessor is of an outdated design, and *encapsulation* (the split between public interface and implementation details) doesn't work in C++ because private fields of a class are part of the public interface.

What do we take from that? Mainly the point about *compilation time*. Headers allow you to recompile only those parts that have changed. This should be supported by virtually any build chain – learn about the `make` program if you are currently doing everything by hand.

Comment: As an aside: Physicists in general know far too little about software development for the amount of code they write, and I immediately recognized the code style you talked about :( Thank you so much for trying to bring a bit of sanity to physics code.

Comment: Good answer. Generalise: all scientists, engineers, economists and business people are guilty of the same sins, plus they won't pay experts to help them get it right. Come the revolution...